# Minimum number of equidistant elements in finite integer sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

For all possible non-decreasing finite sequences, $S_l$, of positive integers  with values in $Z_n = \{0,...,n-1\}$ and size $|S_l|=n, l = 1,2,...,n^n$, what is the minimal size of a maximal set of disjoint triplets $[x_k, x_j, x_i], x_i, x_j, x_k \in S_l$ 
that satisfy the equidistant property:
$x_i - x_j = x_j - x_k, 1 \le k < j < i \le n$.

For example, sequence $S = \{0,1,3,3,4,5,5,7,8\}$, with $9$ values in $Z_9$ has a maximal set of 3 disjoint triplets $[x_k, x_j, x_i]$ with equidistant property:
$[(0,4,8),(1,3,5),(3,5,7)]$

I'm looking for a theory on the minimum bound of such maximal sets for all possible sets $|S_l|=n, l = 1,2,...,n^n$ made by taking $n$ values from $Z_n$ (where, obviously, some values may repeat, etc).

Is there any underlying theory for such a problem? Where would I start researching this? It looks like a problem on the border of abstract algebra, combinatorics, and number theory. Thanks in advance.

(edited for clarity and with some loss of generality)

Comment: Why did you omit [[11,14,17],[12,15,18],[14,17,20],[18,21,24]]?

Comment: Because I meant disjoint triplets. I will add the correction in the question. Thanks. Also, I'm interested in the maximal sets of triplets, which is 4 in both examples, so any solution that is maximal will do.

Comment: What is the condition on the size of $S$? Otherwise, if $|S| \le 2$, you obviously get no such triples.

Comment: Size of S is finite and given. I left it unspecified to make the problem more generic. But the special cases I'm actually interested in have $|S| = n$.

Comment: Just to clarify further, I'm not interested in a way to obtain maximal partitions. This is (likely) equivalent to maximal set coverage problem (Maximum Coverage Problem) which is NP-hard (and in fact I have an algorithm in Haskell to get them - modulo bugs I might have). I'm interested in any reference to some underlying theory that can guarantee a minimum bound on the maximal-size partition.